# Why is this Fibonacci sequence not working?

Tags: python, fibonacci

I can't seem to get this to work; can anyone help?

```
def mystery(n):
    a, b = 0, 1  
    while a < n: 
        print(a)
        a, b = b, a + b
```

It just comes up blank when I run it.

Comment: how are you running it?

Comment: What `n` are you passing?

Comment: Probably an obvious question - Are you actually calling the function and passing in a value `(n)`?

Comment: C'mon guys, downvoting this into oblivion is unnecessarily harsh. This is a pretty reasonable, if basic, question.

Comment: @NPE: (did not vote) I don't see any steps to reproduce the issue here. The function *works* (e.g. it'll print output for any `n > 0`, so we'd need more information to reproduce the problem, if there is any.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: To my mind, it's pretty clear that the OP is failing to call the function (i.e. the code is presented in its entirety). I could, of course, be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

For this to do anything, you need to call the function, for example

```
mystery(10)
```

This prints out

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
```

Answer (score 1):

yeah it took me some time but I have figured it out and also how to input a number as well I will give you the answer.

```
def mystery(n):
   a, b = 0, 1
   while a < n:
      print (a)
      a, b = b, a + b
mystery(int(input("Insert A Number: ")))
```

there you go.

Answer (score 1):

```
def mystery (n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
        print (a)
        a, b = b, a + b

mystery (10)
```